# Self-homeomorphism of punctured unit disk which induces identity-automorphism of fundamental group

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, mapping-class-group

The mapping class group of the closed unit disk $D_n\subset\mathbb{C}$ with $n$  equally spaced points $P$ on the x-axis (0,1) removed is defined as the set of isotopy classes of self-homeomorphisms $D_n\rightarrow D_n$ which fix the boundary: $\phi\partial D_n=\partial D_n$, and permute the distinguished points: $\phi P=P$.

I am considering a representative $\phi:D_n\rightarrow D_n$ of an element of said mapping class group that induces the identity-automorphism of the fundamental group $\pi_1(D_n,x_0)$, i.e. $\phi_*=\text{id}_{\pi_1(D_n,x_0)}$, where $x_0\in\partial D_n$.
I am convinced that $\phi$ has to be homotopic to the identity map $\text{id}_{D_n}$ but am unable to prove it.
I know that since $\phi$ is a homeomorphism, $\phi^{-1}_*$ has to be the identity-automorphism as well, but I fail to see how I could use this.

Also, since $\phi$ fixes all loops, for every point $x$ I can choose some loop $\gamma$ on which $x$ lies, and get some homotopy $H_\gamma$ to a loop $\phi\circ\gamma$, on which $\phi(x)$ lies. But I don't see how I could combine those homotopies to get a well defined homotopy from $\text{id}_{D_n}$ to $\phi$, or whether that is even possible at all.

A hint would be appreciated.

Comment: The fundamental group of a disk is trivial, so all automorphisms are the identity. Do you mean the fundamental group of the punctured disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Choose a basepoint-preserving homotopy equivalence $f:X\to D_n$, where $X$ is a wedge of $n$ circles.  Since $f$ is a homotopy equivalence, it suffices to show that $\phi\circ f\simeq id_{D_n}\circ f=f$.  To show this, you can show that there is a basepoint-preserving homotopy between $\phi\circ f$ and $f$ when restricted to each of the circles of $X$.

Comment: I tried this for some time now. I don't know which map you restrict when you say 'when restricted to each of the circles of X'. I also don't understand how I am supposed to construct a homotopy $\phi\circ f\sim f$. I can give paths $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow X$ and then argue that $f\circ\gamma\sim\gamma$, but this is something I already knew without introducing X. Could you provide me with more detail on how to construct the homotopy $\phi\circ f\sim f$ please. This has to work by elementary means somehow, I didn't take a course in algebraic topology. I only know the def. of fundamental group.

Comment: The space $X$ is just a union of circles $X_1,\dots,X_n$, which overlap at a single point.  To construct a homotopy from $\phi\circ f$ to $f$, you can just construct a homotopy from $\phi\circ f|_{X_i}$ to $f|_{X_i}$ for each $i$ (fixing the basepoint) and then glue those homotopies together.  To get a homotopy from $\phi\circ f|_{X_i}$ to $f|_{X_i}$, notice that $f|_{X_i}$ is just a map from a circle to $D_n$, and homotopy classes of such maps are the same thing as elements of $\pi_1(D_n)$.

Comment: So by wedge you mean something like a 'finite hawaiian earring' where all circles are glued at a single point, as opposed to something like this: oooo ?

Comment: Yes, an $n$-fold [wedge sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedge_sum) of circles.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much. Which result is it that you use to glue together the homotopies?

Comment: You can just use the [pasting lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasting_lemma), viewing $X\times [0,1]$ as the union of the closed subspaces $X_i\times [0,1]$.